# Съезжает элемент в .NET Framework

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, .net-framework

Вот код добавления элементов в форму, который генерируется автоматически:

```
this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(9, 20);
this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(1297, 605);
this->Controls->Add(this->start);
this->Name = L"MyForm";
this->Text = L"MyForm";
this->ResumeLayout(false);
this->PerformLayout();
```

Координаты элемента `this->start` прописаны в пикселях, типо так `this->start->Location = System::Drawing::Point(1002, 463);`

Элемент появляется на своем месте: там, где он был поставлен в конструкторе. Но если мне нужно добавить другой элемент уже где-то ниже в коде, после кода выше, я просто пишу

```
this->Controls->Add(this->another);
```

без каких либо других строк. И тогда элемент съезжает на место, не соответствующее ему в пикселях. В таком случае приходится вручную выравнивать его по пикселям, тысячу раз запуская программу и смотря на его теперешнее положение. Как избежать этого или что не так у меня?

Comment: На C++/CLI полноценные приложения не пишут. Поэтому вам никто не поможет. Никто! / ЗЫ: переходите на C#.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov понятно, спасибо.. ужасно что в вузах заставляют на с++ cli писать

Comment: Используйте компоненты `TableLayoutPantel` или `FlowLayoutPanel` - они сами будут выравнивать элементы, помещённые на них. / Смотрите документацию WinForms - там полно примеров. Смотрите любые книги по C#/WinForms - в большинстве случаев различие с C++/CLI будет только в синтаксисе.